# How can I use Github Actions' concurrency to cancel other jobs, if any of them fail?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have 3 processes that run in my actions on Github:

1. Lint (7 minutes)
2. Backend test (13 minutes)
3. JS tests (2 minutes)

I would like that, if #1 or #3 fail, I cancel all the rest because they all need to pass before the code is valid anyway, and running the test suite is a waste of minutes if I need to push up a lint or JS test fix.

I use concurrency at the top level to prevent duplicate runs, but I understand from the documentation that concurrency can also apply to the job level, but I'm really struggling to find examples of how to implement this.

Here's a really stripped down version of my YAML:

```
name: my-app
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - my_ignore_branch
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
env:
  SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  application-backend-lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    ... execution here ...

  application-backend-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    ... execution here ...
```

With that structure, how can I implement a concurrency strategy to cancel `application-backend-test` if `application-backend-lint` fails? Not that I have tried adding:

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}-tests
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

To each job, but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a different solution, I appended this to the end of my steps,

```
  - name: Cancelling parallel jobs
    if: failure()
    uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2
```

So to use my above example:

```
name: my-app
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - my_ignore_branch
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
env:
  SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  application-backend-lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    ... execution here ...
    - name: Cancelling parallel jobs
      if: failure()
      uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2

  application-backend-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    ... execution here ...
    - name: Cancelling parallel jobs
      if: failure()
      uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2
```